# What is the difference between ** and ^ in python

Tags: java, python

In python if you want to sqaure an int you have to put ** but in java you put ^;
But python didn't give me an error when I did ^ in my code

It just gave me something with no pattern can anyone explain what happens when you use ^ in python?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qowzh.png)

Comment: ^ means bitwise or in C/python. Hence python chose ** for exponent.

Comment: There _are_ languages where `^` means exponentiation.  **Java is not one of them**.

Comment: 'In Java you put ^': no you don't. There is no exponentiation operator in Java. `^` is XOR in both Python and Java.

Answer (score 1):

In python, `**` is the exponentiation operator, and `^` is the XOR operator ([python operators](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp))

XOR is the bitwise XOR of the two numbers. In other words, write each number in binary, then take XOR of the two numbers one place at a time (A XOR B is true if A and B are different, and false if they're the same. 0 is false, 1 is true).

Here's an example computing 5 XOR 3:

```
5 ^ 3
```

```
101 = 5
011 = 3
```

from left to right:

```
1 ^ 0 -> 1
0 ^ 1 -> 1
1 ^ 1 -> 0
0 ^ 0 -> 0
```

```
  101
^ 011
-------
  110
```

so `5^3=6`